# Do Bluetooth repeaters exist?

Tags: bluetooth

We have two Android phones (Vibrants) and a regular land-line at home.  We bought a cordless system that has Bluetooth built-in (Panasonic KX-TGA651) so that we can use the cordless phones to answer our cell phones.

Everything works well. However, we want to place the cordless base in the kitchen, but don't want to have to park our cell phones there. Do Bluetooth repeaters exist that we could use for this purpose?

Comment: You probably got a class 2 bluetooth adapter in the Panasonic.  I tried searching for class 1 (100 meters) cordless phones but I couldn't find any on the internet.  They just don't list bluetooth classes.  I did find that the VTech cordless bluetooth phones are pretty well rated however.

Answer (score 3):

The only repeaters I could find are commercial grade and expensive, I am not sure they are compatible with consumer bluetooth or not, doubtful.

examples:

http://www.solutron.de/Bluetooth/Bluetooth-Repeaters

http://www.engadget.com/2006/11/22/aircable-offers-up-28-mile-bluetooth-range-extender/

http://www.gener8green.com/g8g-shop-solar-pv-accessories-sma-sma-bluetooth-repeater-with-power-supply---btrep-in-1434

Comment: 28 mile repeater?  Dang, I needed 30 miles :P

Answer (score 3):

I have found a site which lists the capabilities of the Bluetooth device as "Multipoint Forwarding, SPP + DUN Profiles, and Bluetooth Repeater Mode" 
http://www.conserver.com/consoles/BlueConsole/

I am thinking of getting this, powering it with a 9V battery and streaming audio from my phone to this, then boosting the signal and streaming it to my class 1 Bluetooth stereo headset (Motorola S705).

I used to use a Motorola Milestone and could get 30 to 50m between the two, but my new Samsung Galaxy Note limits about 25m, which is not going to work for me sometimes.

Comment: Looks awesome -- if you find any for sale anywhere, post a link please!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately none of the above equipment suggestions will work unless both the base and the hand held receiver use SPP (Serial Port Profile) as some Android phones do. Most cell phones with the link to cell feature use the Hands Free Profile.

The SENA Parani SD1000 along with most other serial adapters and commercially available repeaters use the Serial Port Profile. A base station or a handheld using the Hands Free Profile would not appear for pairing.

Answer (score 0):

If you had two Bluetooth network adapters on a PC you could bridge the connections and that might function as a repeater.

Answer (score 0):

You can connect 2 of these end to end and it acts as a repeater.

http://www.sena.com/products/industrial_bluetooth/sd1000.php

They are a bit expensive and require a power supply but the are class 1 devices so they have up to 100m range using 9DBi antenna.