# Use multiple blutooth dongles to make one giant inhouse repeater

Tags: bluetooth, repeater

current scenario:

Sony Bluetooth smartwatch that connects to a smart phone via bluetooth. Phone sends info to watch like text messages etc.

The issue:

Limited range from phone to watch

what is needed:

Is there a way to use multpiple computers and bluetooth dongles that will act as a repeater to cover entire house?

for instance:

Phone is on first floor, blutooth signal normaly can not make it to second floor.
Use bluetooth dongle on computer in first floor, to repeat phone bluetooth signal up to dongle on computer on second floor . second floor computer dongle then repeats to my watch.

Basically using multpiple computers and dongles as a signal repeater.

possible?

Answer (score 0):

According to a fairly recent SU question, [the jury's out on whether BT repeaters exist and are usable in consumer applications](https://superuser.com/questions/247868/do-bluetooth-repeaters-exist). If it's that important to you, you could probably *do* it with a enterprise BT repeater, but they're certainly not common little devices that you can stick in a computer's USB socket like a wifi adapter.

Why not... just... take your phone with you?