# Can I boost or repeat a bluetooth signal?

Tags: bluetooth

I am getting into smoking meat. The smoker is about 500 feet from the kitchen. I have a thermometer that is Bluetooth enabled. It is paired with an ios device. But I cant be in the kitchen and be connected. So I need to know if there is a way to repeat that signal or boost it somehow so that I can be in the kitchen and be connected at the same time.

Comment: [Related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27804605/is-it-possible-to-repeat-or-redistribute-a-bluetooth-signal).....also [Related](http://superuser.com/questions/247868/do-bluetooth-repeaters-exist)  [SMA BLUETOOTH REPEATER OUTDOOR - Soligent](http://www.soligent.net/uploads/products/29387_6.pdf)